# Show loading bar until method completed

Tags: android

I have one method and one bitmap

```
private static Bitmap do(Bitmap bit){
 //Show loading until return;
return bit;
}
```

When i use the following code it takes about 30 seconds or more. What i want is to show a loading bar until the method completes

`bitmap = do(bitmap);`

How can i achieve that?

**Example**

What i do to **resize** a bitmap:

```
Bitmap bit;
bit = getResizedBitmap(bit,100,100);//takes 20 seconds
image.setImageBitmap(bit);
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
            return resizedBitmap;
        }
```

How can i get the same result using `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** You should put the method in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

**Second:** You display the progress bar before calling the method. Then, you hide it when the method finishes.

---

**Example:**

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, Boolean> {
     protected Boolean doInBackground(Bitmap... bit) {
         //show progress bar
         //call your method
         return true;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean done) {
         //hide progress bar
     }
 }
```

And you run your AsyncTask like this:

```
Bitmap bit;
new MyTask().execute(bit);
//Now your Bitmap object is ready.
```

Comment: whats the difference between bitmap and bitmap[]

Comment: `bitmap` is one Bitmap object, `bitmap[]` is an array.

Comment: to excecute i need to create AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, Boolean> bit; but i still want to use Bitmap bit;

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Is the sample code not working for you? What went wrong?

Comment: I don't see why AsyncTask won't work in your case. You just take `getResizedBitmap()` method and put it in `MyTask` inner class and call it from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: i cant excecute AsyncTask: bit = new MyTask().execute(bit);

Comment: @Device because you are doing it wrong! don't assign it to `bit`. Just call `new MyTask().execute(bit);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86543/discussion-between-device-and-iturki).